# mysql natural sorting

Tags: mysql, sorting, natural-sort

I have table like `server(id,name,ip)`. When I'm trying to sort results by name, I get:

`srv1,srv10,srv11,srv2,srv6`

but I need the results like `srv1,srv2,srv6,srv10,srv11`

One idea I know is

```
ORDER BY LENGTH(name), name
```

but I have different lengths in name column

What do I need to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting string column containing numbers in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939518/sorting-string-column-containing-numbers-in-sql)

Comment: I was not found worked code for my issue in that question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try this:

```
SELECT id,name,ip,CONVERT(SUBSTRING(name FROM 4),UNSIGNED INTEGER) num
ORDER BY num;
```

Answer (score 1):

Natural sorting is not implemented in MySQL. You should try a different approach. In this example I assume that the server name has always the same template (i.e. srv###).

```
select
    name, 
    mid(name, 4, LENGTH(name)-3) as num, 
    CAST(mid(name, 4, LENGTH(name)-3) AS unsigned) as parsed_num 
from server
order by parsed_num asc;
```

As I said, this approach is very specific, since you assume that the first 3 characters are to be ignored. This could be misleading and difficult to handle if you change the template.

You could chose to add a column to the table, let's call it `prefix` in which you set the prefix name for the server (in your example it will be `srv` for each one). Then you could use:

```
select
    name,
    prefix,
    mid(name, LENGTH(prefix) + 1, LENGTH(name)-LENGTH(prefix)) as num, 
    CAST(mid(name, LENGTH(prefix) + 1, LENGTH(name)-LENGTH(prefix)) AS unsigned) as parsed_num  
from server
order by parsed_num asc;
```

obtaining a more robust approach.

Comment: Thank you but I names has no single template (it may be host#, sw#, csw# etc.)

Comment: In that case you should add, for each server, the corresponding prefix in the column `prefix`, the use the `order by prefix asc, parsed_num asc` clause

Comment: If you put in the database different server names (as in `host###`, `sw###`, etc.) the previous answer solution will simply not work, because it will assume that the prefix will always be 3 characters long. Try the approach I suggested, then let me know if it works or not for you.