# Convert partially non-numeric text into number in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to convert text into a number within MySQL query? I have a column with an identifier that consists a name and a number in the format of "name-number". The column has VARCHAR type. I want to sort the rows according to the number (rows with the same name) but the column is sorted according to do character order, i.e.

```
name-1
name-11
name-12
name-2
```

If I cut off the number, can I convert the 'varchar' number into the 'real' number and use it to sort the rows? I would like to obtain the following order.

```
name-1
name-2
name-11
name-12
```

I cannot represent the number as a separate column.

**edited 2011-05-11 9:32**

I have found the following solution `... ORDER BY column * 1`. If the name will not contain any numbers is it safe to use that solution?

Comment: _name_ is exactly **name** or it can be any character? I mean: is it a string four chars long or is a real name?

Comment: `name` can be any sequence of letters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql natural sorting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947765/mysql-natural-sorting)

Answer (score 286, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT field,CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field,'-',-1),UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS num
FROM table
ORDER BY num;
```

Comment: could you add an explanation and a link to the documentation?

Comment: My string is like "name-abc12". By adding your code, it only works if the initial characters after "-" not starts with a letter. @Marco Can you tell me a way to ignore the letters without a where condition?

Comment: @Eduardo my query is supposed to get the string after the "-" and convert it into a number (it MUST be a number). In your case I'd go on using a regular expression probably...

Comment: @Marco regular expression did it, thank you for the tip.

Comment: [More info](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring_index.asp) on this command

Comment: @Eduardo Marco is using `SUBSTRING_INDEX` which uses a given separator (`-` in this case) to split the string in "columns" and return the portion of that separation that you ask for (with the third argument). All details in the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Answer (score 37):

You can use [`SUBSTRING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) and [`CONVERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert):

```
SELECT stuff
FROM table
WHERE conditions
ORDER BY CONVERT(SUBSTRING(name_column, 6), SIGNED INTEGER);
```

Where `name_column` is the column with the "name-" values. The `SUBSTRING` removes everything up before the sixth character (i.e. the "name-" prefix) and then the `CONVERT` converts the left over to a real integer.

**UPDATE**: Given the changing circumstances in the comments (i.e. the prefix can be anything), you'll have to throw a [`LOCATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) in the mix:

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(SUBSTRING(name_column, LOCATE('-', name_column) + 1), SIGNED INTEGER);
```

This of course assumes that the non-numeric prefix doesn't have any hyphens in it but the relevant comment says that:

> `name` can be any sequence of letters

so that should be a safe assumption.

Comment: Answering my comment, he told us _name_ can be any sequence of chars, so I'm not sure you can use `SUBSTRING(name_column, 6)`. I know, you posted it when he didn't tell us this...

Comment: @Marco: Thanks for the heads up, I added an update that should take care of the new information about the prefixes. But yeah, your SUBSTRING_INDEX is nicer.

Answer (score 29):

Simply use CAST,

```
CAST(column_name AS UNSIGNED)
```

The type for the cast result can be one of the following values:

```
BINARY[(N)]
CHAR[(N)]
DATE
DATETIME
DECIMAL[(M[,D])]
SIGNED [INTEGER]
TIME
UNSIGNED [INTEGER]
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use [CAST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) to convert from string to int. e.g. `SELECT CAST('123' AS INTEGER);`

Comment: Is that version specific?  I need to use `SELECT CAST('123' AS SIGNED INTEGER);` or `SELECT CAST('123' AS UNSIGNED INTEGER);` to get it to work.

Answer (score 10):

```
SELECT *, CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, '-', -1) AS UNSIGNED) as num FROM tableName ORDER BY num;
```

Comment: Are you sure that the ORDER BY uses num as a number without using CONVERT? I'm not sure, but it can be.. I'm just asking myself :)

Answer (score 9):

one simple way SELECT '123'+ 0

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Comment: This did not answer the question but it was the answer i was looking for.

Comment: your solution is the most elegant and practical - unfortunately you didnt provide it in the context of the question with specific expression for given example - please modify it to be specific.

Answer (score 5):

```
cast(REGEXP_REPLACE(NameNumber, '[^0-9]', '') as UNSIGNED)
```

Comment: Exactly what I want :)

Comment: It's my fortune, I came out helpful for you.

Answer (score 3):

To get number try with `SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, '-', 1)` then convert.

Comment: You need to change 1 to -1. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Answer (score 2):

if your primary key is a string in a format like

ABC/EFG/EE/13/123(sequence number)
this sort of string can be easily used for sorting with the delimiter("/")

we can use the following query to order a table with this type of key

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLE_NAME` ORDER BY 
CONVERT(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(`key_column_name`), 1, LOCATE('/', REVERSE(`key_column_name`)) - 1)) , UNSIGNED INTEGER) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier to use regex_replace function to strip off all non numeric values from the field and then sort.

```sql
SELECT field , CONVERT(REGEXP_REPLACE(field,'[^0-9]',''),UNSIGNED) AS num FROM your_table ORDER BY num;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select
    `a`.uuid,
    concat('1',REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(`a`.uuid,'-',''),'b','11'),'c','12'),'d','13'),'e','14'),'f','15'),'a','10')),
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: This one may just be responding to the title of this post - converting text to number (in this case a text uuid string) -- using replace (or pretty much anything else) is generally faster than a regex. This also suggests the idea of using a uuid string as primary key. A plain old autoincrement or perhaps a binary uuid would be faster than conversion to string if that is the goal in this case.

Answer (score -5):

A generic way to do :

```
SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY LENTH(your_column) ASC, your_column ASC
```