# Key Value Pair Comparison

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

```
SELECT wposts.*, wpostmeta.*
    FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta2, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta3
    WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
        AND wposts.ID = wpostmeta2.post_id
        AND wposts.ID = wpostmeta3.post_id
        AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'listing_subtype'
            AND wpostmeta.meta_value = '$search_home_type'
        AND wpostmeta2.meta_key = 'district'
            AND wpostmeta2.meta_value = '$search_district'
        AND wpostmeta3.meta_key = 'price_current'
            AND wpostmeta3.meta_value IS >= '$search_price_min' AND <= '$search_price_max'
        AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
        AND wposts.post_type = 'vreb_property'
    ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC
```

The line `AND wpostmeta3.meta_value IS >= '$search_price_min' AND <= '$search_price_max'` is trying to make sure that the **meta_value** of the **meta_key** `price_current` is GREATER THAN `$search_price_min` and LESS THAN `$search_price_max`

This isn't working...

```
[You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<= '100000' AND wposts.post_status = 'publish' AND wposts.post_type = 'vreb_' at line 11]
```

Comment: is it showing an invalid SQL statement or just not returning the results you want?

Comment: Invalid statement right at that point. I've tried adding brackets around that one statement, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Get rid of the `IS`  in `IS >= `  Should be  `wpostmeta3.meta_value >= '$search_price_min' AND <= '$search_price_max'`

Comment: (maybe try a BETWEEN, `AND wpostmeta3.meta_value BETWEEN '$search_price_min' and '$search_price_max'`)

Comment: Yep, I bet @MichaelBerkowski is right

Comment: No, sorry. that doesn't work. `AND wpostmeta3.meta_value >= '$search_price_min' AND <= '$search_price_max'` makes no difference.

Comment: @dcolumbus What does your error checking report? There was a clear syntax error, so if you have other syntax errors, you need to find them. First get the query working in a MySQL client, then put it into PHP.

Comment: convert from string to float or int ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960620/convert-text-into-number-in-mysql-query

Comment: I added the error above.

Comment: @dcolumbus You need something on both sides of `<=`.  `AND wpostmeta3.meta_value <= '$search_price_max'`

Comment: ...or use `wppostmeta3.meta_value BETWEEN '$search_price_min' AND '$search_price_max'`

Comment: Tried that... got that following error: `Unknown column 'wppostmeta3.meta_value' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Because I misspelled it. Check your table aliases and put in the correct one.

Comment: Caught that. Now I don't get any results ... which I know is not true. At least there's no error. Any other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AND wpostmeta3.meta_value IS >= '$search_price_min' AND <= '$search_price_max'
```

needs to be

```
AND wpostmeta3.meta_value >= '$search_price_min'
AND wpostmeta3.meta_value <= '$search_price_max'
```

Comment: That's exactly why. Thanks, inhan. Any reason why my results seem to work if my `search_price_max` is 800000 but nothing lower? It's so odd because the `current_price` is only **59000**

Comment: @dcolumbus Well it depends. What is the datatype of the `meta_value` column and what are min & max values you're using in your query?

Comment: Well, the `meta_value` should be a string ... and the min is `0` while the max is `1000000000` or whatever. It seems to always return a result if the number is not starting with a `1` ... correction, anything after `600000`

Comment: If you're trying to evaluate a value against numbers why are you using single quotes around them at first place?

Comment: THATS IT! Of course! The single quotes stops the numbers from being able to be evaluated! Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to cast those numbers to integers if you're getting their values from the user - just in case, for security reasons.

Comment: $search_price_min = (int)$params['search_price_min']; ?

Comment: Exactly. If these are provided by you explicitly you don't need to worry, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
AND <= '$search_price_max'
```

and what should be `<=`? You missed the argument for that operator: That's the error.

Probably you meant:

```
AND wpostmeta3.meta_value <= '$search_price_max'
```