# custom sort in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sorting

The data below is a string column sorted in ascending order:

```
1/44/104/66
1/44/104/66/137
1/44/104/66/138
1/44/104/66/139
1/44/104/66/140
1/44/104/66/141
1/44/104/66/142
1/44/104/66/143
1/44/104/66/67
1/44/104/66/68
1/44/104/66/69
```

But I would like to sort it like this:

```
1/44/104/66
1/44/104/66/67
1/44/104/66/68
1/44/104/66/69
1/44/104/66/137
1/44/104/66/138
1/44/104/66/139
1/44/104/66/140
1/44/104/66/141
1/44/104/66/142
1/44/104/66/143
```

Comment: AFIK this is not possible in SQL.

Comment: Are you just sorting by the last column? In plain english, how would you describe the sort?

Comment: You might find some answers here regarding casting a field as an integer for numeric sorting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686849/sorting-varchar-field-numerically-in-mysql

Comment: where should the string `1/44/105/32/25` end up in your dataset?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960620/convert-text-into-number-in-mysql-query

Answer (score 0):

For the data that you have, this should work:

```
order by length(col), col
```

However, this assumes that the only difference is in that last column.

Comment: What if string A is larger than string B (numerically) but string A is *shorter* than string B? PS: I (was) the downvoter but the user didn't give enough details for this answer to be incorrect, per se. Just thought I'd point that out

Comment: @Evan . . . My answer clearly states that it works for the data provided in the question, with the assumption that only the last field changes.  Is there something about the answer you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

you could try something along the lines of:

```
select
    Name
from TableOne
ORDER BY Cast(Replace(Name, "/", "") as UNSIGNED)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(DATA_COLUMN,"/",-1) AS UNSIGNED) ;
```

How it works :

1: In your original order by, the order was not correct since it was  comparing lexographically for strings, whereas you wanted ordering based on integer value.

2.. In this solution, `SUBSTRING_INDEX` extracts the last value after `/` , and then casts it as an integer to give you the required order.

3.. You can extend the same solution to order by second last, third last numbers in your data pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a beautiful query, but it should do what you need:

```
SELECT s
FROM
  yourtable
ORDER BY
  s + 0,
  CASE WHEN LENGTH(s)-LENGTH(REPLACE(s, '/',''))>0
       THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(s, '/', 2), '/', -1)+0
       ELSE 0 END,
  CASE WHEN LENGTH(s)-LENGTH(REPLACE(s, '/',''))>1
       THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(s, '/', 3), '/', -1)+0
       ELSE 0 END,
  CASE WHEN LENGTH(s)-LENGTH(REPLACE(s, '/',''))>2
       THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(s, '/', 4), '/', -1)+0
       ELSE 0 END,
  CASE WHEN LENGTH(s)-LENGTH(REPLACE(s, '/',''))>3
       THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(s, '/', 5), '/', -1)+0
       ELSE 0 END
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e5e3/2).