# error while inserting data using dynamic insert datatype varchar cannot convert to int

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, dynamicquery

i have following query,which is used to insert data to table dynamically,i have checked the data type of table and parameter which im passing both are same,but still having following error:

---

4
1
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 43
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'insert into tblAccessRights (RoleId,CustomerId,IsCustomerExclusive,SubcustomerId,
IsSubCustomerExclusive,ClinicId,CreatedBy,CreatedDate,IsDeleted,IsActive)
values(' to data type int.

---

this is my query plz check

```
declare @SubcustomerId varchar(max)    
set @SubcustomerId = '4,5'  

declare @IsSubCustomerExclusive varchar(max)
set @IsSubCustomerExclusive = '1,0'
declare  
@RoleId int ,    
@CustomerId int,    
@IsCustomerExclusive int,    

@ClinicId varchar(max)=null,    
@CreatedBy int,    
@CreatedDate datetime,    
@ModifiedBy int,    
@ModifiedDate datetime,    
@IsDeleted bit,    
@IsActive bit,    
@RoleName varchar(50) 
set  
@RoleId =24     
set @IsCustomerExclusive =0    

set @ClinicId =null  
set @CreatedBy=null  
set @CreatedDate =null   
set @ModifiedDate =null    
set @IsDeleted=0    
set @IsActive =1    
set @RoleName='ts1'   


declare @sql varchar(max)    

while(len(@SubcustomerId) > 0 and LEN(@IsSubCustomerExclusive)>=0)  
begin    
  print left(@SubcustomerId, charindex(',', @SubcustomerId+',')-1)  
  print left(@IsSubCustomerExclusive, charindex(',', @IsSubCustomerExclusive+',')-1) 
 if(LEN(@IsSubCustomerExclusive)=0 )  
 begin  
   set @IsSubCustomerExclusive='0'  
 end  

   set @sql='insert into tblAccessRights        (RoleId,CustomerId,IsCustomerExclusive,SubcustomerId,    
IsSubCustomerExclusive,ClinicId,CreatedBy,CreatedDate,IsDeleted,IsActive)    
values('+@RoleId+','+@CustomerId+','+@IsCustomerExclusive+','+left(@SubcustomerId,   charindex(',', @SubcustomerId+',')-1)+',    
  '+left(@IsSubCustomerExclusive, charindex(',',  @IsSubCustomerExclusive+',')-1)+','+@ClinicId+','+@CreatedBy+','+@CreatedDate+','+@IsDeleted      +','+@IsActive+')'
print @sql    

   --exec(@sql)    
     set @SubcustomerId = stuff(@SubcustomerId, 1, charindex(',', @SubcustomerId+','), '')   
       set @IsSubCustomerExclusive = stuff(@IsSubCustomerExclusive, 1, charindex(',',  @IsSubCustomerExclusive+','), '')     
        end
```

m i doing wrong in query????,plz help

```
pid int 
RoleId  int 
CustomerId  int 
IsCustomerExclusive int 
SubcustomerId   varchar(MAX)    
IsSubCustomerExclusive  varchar(MAX)    
ClinicId    varchar(MAX)    
CreatedBy   varchar(50) 
CreatedDate datetime    
ModifiedBy  varchar(50) 
ModifiedDate    datetime    
IsDeleted   bit 
IsActive    bit
```

this is my table structure

Comment: you orobably pass your SQL string as parameter where an int is expected somehwere.

Comment: Is it mysql or SQL server? You added both tags. SQL server i guess

Comment: @ Pleun:its is sql server 2008

Answer (score 0):

for sample:

```
   SELECT field,CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field,'-',-1),UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS num
    FROM table
    ORDER BY num;
```

[convert text into number in mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960620/convert-text-into-number-in-mysql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Your RoleID is an integer, so u try do an implicit cast: 'insert into table ......' as int

you should trying to do somthing like 'foo ' + CONVERT(varchar,@RoleId) + ' ba'
than you get: 'foo 24 ba'

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

set @sql='insert into tblAccessRights        (RoleId,CustomerId,IsCustomerExclusive,SubcustomerId,
IsSubCustomerExclusive,ClinicId,CreatedBy,CreatedDate,IsDeleted,IsActive)
values(' + CONVERT(varchar, @RoleId) + ',' + CONVERT(varchar, @CustomerId) + ...

Comment: you declared @RoleID as an int.
if u try to concatenate an int with an varchar, the dbms trys to cast the varchar as an int, but you want to cast the other way:  int as varchar.

Comment: look at the refrence:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276862%28v=sql.80%29.aspx
its says:
Returns the data type of the argument with the highest precedence. For more information, see Data Type Precedence.