# Convert/encode string to numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking around to encode/cast/convert a string into numbers within a query. Like `ASCII()` but it only returns the left-most character to its relative code. Is there any function or method available on this topic? -*which is actually decode-able*

***JUST For example***:

```
METHOD("test-string") # Outputs: 25478596325417
```

Comment: Please give some examples of what you are trying to do and what you are trying to accomplish.  Are you looking for a loss-less (reversible) encoding?  Are you looking for numbers of a specific length?  Is there a particular set of values that you want to convert?  what do you want to do with the numbers after conversion?

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960620/convert-text-into-number-in-mysql-query.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want to convert a set of sequential characters - *strings actually* - to numbers which I can decode them later. Most likely their ASCII codes. Example added

Comment: @user1929959 I saw it before. It doesn't fit my case.

Comment: @RachelGallen That doesn't result in what I wanted.

Comment: How does "test-string" compute to 25478596325417?

Comment: @Simon That's an imaginary example, man!

Comment: What are you going to do with this number?  Are you going to store it as a number?  That will put a limit on how big it can be.

Comment: @Hogan I'm going to store it like that but strictly not Integer or other numeric types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for strings up to 8 characters long.

To encode:

```
SELECT CONV(HEX(string), 16, 10);
```

To decode:

```
SELECT UNHEX(CONV(number, 10, 16));
```

MySQL supports integers up to 64 bit long, and this method uses 8 bits per character. Therefore using this method you can store up to 64 / 8 = 8 characters in an integer.

Comment: Where does that limitation come from?

Comment: I added an explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If hexadecimal is good enough for your application, then then function `hex()` does what you want.  For instance, you can try:

```
select hex('abc'), hex('abcd')
```

This will work on arbitrary strings.  If this doesn't quite work, then perhaps there is a way to convert the hex representation to something appropriate.

By the way, `unhex()` will return the original string.

Comment: But HEX may include A to F numbers. *I need Integers only!*

Comment: @revo What's the greatest length your string may have?

Comment: hmmmm maybe 20 and yet it's a guess.

Comment: @revo Have a look at the range of the [INTEGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html) and [DECIMAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fixed-point-types.html) data types. Won't you rather convert to a string?

Comment: Sorry, I think I made you misunderstood things. I meant numeric values by "Integers".

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
SELECT CAST(HEX(your_string) AS DECIMAL);
```

*I admit, I didn't test it, but it should work.*

**EDIT:**

Some other databases (e.g. Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL) have the function TRANSLATE() for it. Unfortunately MySQL does not support it. And as far as I know no replacement for this function in MySQL exists currently. So using nested REPLACE() is probably the only option currently.

Comment: @pdw `CAST(HEX("mmm") AS DECIMAL)` outputs `6`. How you can decode `6` to `mmm` then?

Comment: it has it's own limitations :( See my edit above. Nested REPLACE is the only way to support strings of any length.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
 COMPRESS('ABC)
```

To get a binary string that is not the string.  It can compress an arbitrary size.  But it is not clear what you are going to do with the number -- or how you need to store it.

Comment: `COMPRESS` output isn't only numeric values. I need a conversion to numbers and have this ability to decode the main string from those numbers. See others answer. Thanks