# My SQL casting an comparing in one query?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, casting

The SQL query:

```
SELECT badgename FROM badges WHERE stock < desiredstock
```

Carried out on this table:

[image: Table]

Should Yield

```
Summit Everest, Elderly Management Badge
```

Yet it yields nothing, and no error is produced.

I hypothisie that since both `stock` and `desiredstock` are columns with `VARCHARS`, the Query cannot be carried out as you can't compare two strings mathematically.

So is it possible to rewrite the query so both `stock` and `desiredstock` values are casted as `VARINTS`?

Comment: yes. try one of the solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960620/convert-text-into-number-in-mysql-query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert text into number in MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960620/convert-text-into-number-in-mysql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the soluuon. Thanks for the link to answer in comments.

```
SELECT badgename FROM badges WHERE CAST(stock AS UNSIGNED) < CAST(desiredstock AS UNSIGNED)
```