# How to perform integer arithmetic to a string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, syntax, char

I need to increase a value by 1 in MySQL that isn't saved as an Integer: It is saved instead as a String because it may start with a `0`, for instance: `01212120211112`. I want to set this value to `01212120211113`.

The "number" is always 14 char long (including the 0 on the beginning) and it will never get longer or shorter.

1. I want to convert it to an Integer
2. set it + 1
3. Convert back to String
4. add a 0 to begin til a length of 14 chars.

Can anyone help me with the syntax?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960620/convert-text-into-number-in-mysql-query) out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the fact you have always a fixed  length string You could use convert  ..  and lpad see the various function in sample

```
 select CONVERT('01212120211112',UNSIGNED INTEGER)
```

.

```
 select CONVERT('01212120211112',UNSIGNED INTEGER) + 1
```

.

```
 select lpad(CONVERT('01212120211112',UNSIGNED INTEGER) + 1 , 14, '0')
```