# SQL order string as number

Tags: mysql, sql, string, numbers, sql-order-by

I have numbers saved as `VARCHAR` to a MySQL database. I can not make them `INT` due to some other depending circumstances.

It is taking them as character not as number while sorting.

In database I have

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10...
```

On my page it shows ordered list like this:

```
1 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

How can I make it appear ordered by numbers ascending?

Comment: @Oded You can have some arbitrary data (e.g. settings), which you want to order by its numeric value only in very special cases.

Comment: very interesting article - is for MSSQL but should be relatively similar for MySQL: https://www.essentialsql.com/use-sql-server-to-sort-alphanumeric-values/

Answer (score 366, accepted):

If possible you should change the data type of the column to a number if you only store numbers anyway.

If you can't do that then cast your column value to an `integer` *explicitly* with

```
select col from yourtable
order by cast(col as unsigned)
```

or *implicitly* for instance with a mathematical operation which forces a conversion to number

```
select col from yourtable
order by col + 0
```

BTW MySQL converts strings from left to right. Examples:

```
string value  |  integer value after conversion
--------------+--------------------------------
'1'           |  1
'ABC'         |  0   /* the string does not contain a number, so the result is 0 */
'123miles'    |  123 
'$123'        |  0   /* the left side of the string does not start with a number */
```

Comment: order by col * 1  works perfect. What is the magic behind this? Sorry I am not professional so this might be silly question but How *1 makes it change to number?

Comment: MySQL automatically converts the string to a number to make the multiplication with `1`

Comment: The first option is most appropriate one, the second has an extra step, but it works non the less.

Comment: I would be worried about NaN results when using the second option when any non-integer characters may be present. I would opt for the first option, which clearly seems the best way to handle it anyway.

Comment: and if you have mixed string and number and want them both sorted, use "order by col * 1, col"

Comment: except when the column contains text with numbers, e.g. "part-1", "part-2", "part-10", "part-11", "part-3"

Comment: What does the second option do if the string is a decimal, like `1.3` - Does it convert it to a decimal, or does performing a mathematical operation only convert to integers?

Comment: @superphonic: The result will be `decimal`.

Comment: In Oracle SQL you can use `order by to_number(col)`

Comment: In Oracle SQL, "order by cast(col as unsigned)" seems doesn't work. Though "order by col + 0" and as Stevoisiak mentioned "order by to_number(col)" works.

Answer (score 97):

Another way, without using a single cast.

(For people who use JPA 2.0, where no casting is allowed)

```
select col from yourtable
order by length(col),col
```

EDIT: only works for positive integers

Comment: this is a good one, thats worked with column that also contain both int and string

Comment: This will not work in all cases. Off the top of head, cases that will not work are mixes of whole numbers with; negative numbers, numbers with leading zeros, numbers with fractions and words and numbers combined.

Comment: great solution without any casting and juggling types around, +1

Comment: didn't seem to work at the first sight, but it worked! Thank you!

Comment: how to specify asc or desc order in this sort?

Answer (score 38):

**Another and simple way**

`ORDER BY ABS(column_name)`

Answer (score 23):

The column I'm sorting with has any combination of alpha and numeric, so I used the suggestions in this post as a starting point and came up with this.

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (ID VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES ('XYZ300');
INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES ('XYZ1002');
INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES ('106');
INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES ('206');
INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES ('1002');
INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES ('J206');
INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES ('J1002');

SELECT ID, (CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(ID) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) IsNum
FROM @tmp
ORDER BY IsNum, LEN(ID), ID;
```

Results

```
ID
------------------------
106
206
1002
J206
J1002
XYZ300
XYZ1002
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You may simply use `1 - ISNUMERIC(ID)` instead of `(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(ID) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)` to change 0 to 1 and vise versa.

Answer (score 8):

This works for me.

```
select * from tablename
order by cast(columnname as int) asc
```

Comment: can you explain why?

Comment: the most simple answer, that does exactly what is needed, cast the string to an int , then order by that int in ascending order, no funky stuff :)

Answer (score 7):

Another way to convert.

If you have string field, you can transform it or its numerical part the following way: add leading zeros to make all integer strings having equal length.

```
ORDER BY CONCAT( REPEAT(  "0", 18 - LENGTH( stringfield ) ) , stringfield )
```

or order by part of a field something like 'tensymbols13', 'tensymbols1222' etc.

```
ORDER BY CONCAT( REPEAT(  "0", 18 - LENGTH( LEFT( stringfield , 10 ) ) ) , LEFT( stringfield , 10 ) )
```

Answer (score 5):

This will handle negative numbers, fractions, string, everything:

```
ORDER BY ISNUMERIC(col) DESC, Try_Parse(col AS decimal(10,2)), col;
```

Answer (score 4):

I was looking also a sorting fields that has letter prefix. Here is what i found out the solution. This might help who is looking for the same solution.

Field Values:

```
FL01,FL02,FL03,FL04,FL05,...FL100,...FL123456789

select SUBSTRING(field,3,9) as field from table order by SUBSTRING(field,3,10)*1 desc
```

`SUBSTRING(field,3,9)` i put 9 because 9 is way enough for me to hold max 9 digits integer values.

So the result will be 
123456789
123456788
123456787
...
100
99
...
2
1

Answer (score -1):

If you are using AdonisJS and have mixed IDs such as ABC-202, ABC-201..., you can combine raw queries with Query Builder and implement the solution above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25061144/4040835) as follows:

```
const sortField =
  'membership_id'
const sortDirection =
  'asc'
const subquery = UserProfile.query()
  .select(
    'user_profiles.id',
    'user_profiles.user_id',
    'user_profiles.membership_id',
    'user_profiles.first_name',
    'user_profiles.middle_name',
    'user_profiles.last_name',
    'user_profiles.mobile_number',
    'countries.citizenship',
    'states.name as state_of_origin',
    'user_profiles.gender',
    'user_profiles.created_at',
    'user_profiles.updated_at'
  )
  .leftJoin(
    'users',
    'user_profiles.user_id',
    'users.id'
  )
  .leftJoin(
    'countries',
    'user_profiles.nationality',
    'countries.id'
  )
  .leftJoin(
    'states',
    'user_profiles.state_of_origin',
    'states.id'
  )
  .orderByRaw(
    `SUBSTRING(:sortField:,3,15)*1 ${sortDirection}`,
    {
      sortField: sortField,
    }
  )
  .paginate(
    page,
    per_page
  )
```

**NOTES:** 
In this line: `SUBSTRING(:sortField:,3,15)*1 ${sortDirection}`,

1. **'3'** stands for the index number of the last non-numerical character before the digits. If your mixed ID is "ABC-123," your index number will be 4.
2. **'15'** is used to catch as any number of digits as possible after the hyphen.
3. **'1'** performs a mathematical operation on the substring which effectively casts the substring to a number.

Ref 1: You can read more about parameter bindings in raw queries here: https://knexjs.org/#Raw-Bindings
Ref 2: Adonis Raw Queries: https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/query-builder#_raw_queries

Answer (score -4):

Alter your field to be INT instead of VARCHAR.

> I can not make them INT due to some other depending circumstances.

Then fix the depending circumstances first.  Otherwise you are working around the real underlying issue.  Using a MySQL CAST is an option, but it's masking your bad schema which should be fixed.