# mysql sort alphabetical and number

Tags: mysql

I have an array that I want to sort alphabetically but also by the number at the end.

```
"SELECT DISTINCT Number FROM database WHERE 1 Order By Number ASC";
```

Here is how it currently sorts:

```
Number 1
Number 10
Number 11
Number 2
Number 3
Number 4
Number 5
Number 6
Number 7
Number 8
Number 9
The End
```

This is how I want it to sort:

```
Number 1
Number 2
Number 3
Number 4
Number 5
Number 6
Number 7
Number 8
Number 9
Number 10
Number 11
The End
```

Comment: Looks like your number column is a string value. You could try casting it to an integer before ordering it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Natural Sort in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153633/natural-sort-in-mysql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL order string as number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808573/sql-order-string-as-number)

Answer (score 8):

Add another sort condition:

```
Order By LENGTH(Number), Number;
```

This works because a longer number is also a bigger number; for numbers of the same length, you can make a textual comparison, because `'0' < '1' .... < '9'`

Comment: Is this going to work always, 'cause I really feel like there could be some hidden catch.

Comment: @Aquillo I've added an explanation why it works. Feel free to find a case where it gives the wrong results :)

Comment: Since Taryn made a comment on this for another answer, what if the preceding string (in this case 'Number') is not always 7 chars? Your length would be messed up.

Comment: @Aquillo This logically still assumes the prefix is the same, even though the length itself is not fixed; if I knew more, I could suggest using `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to sort left first, then right. But that might fail for `The End`.

Comment: You're right, noticed it too. But your solution would put `The end` up front too, since the length is smaller? (Still think you got a nice approach there, though feel like this is a bad database design)

Comment: @Aquillo Yeah, it doesn't help that natural sorting is pretty much an absent feature in MySQL :(

Comment: This fails for me with this data: `Version 1.2, Version 1.3, Version 1.8, Version 1.9, Version 1.10, Version 3.0, Version 3.3`. Using this solution results in the longer number coming last which is incorrect. The longest number, `1.10`, should come after `1.9` and before `3.0`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :-

```
SELECT distinct numberr FROM tablename Order By cast(substring(numberr,7) as unsigned int) ASC ;
```

Its working fine.

Out put :-

```
Number 1
Number 2
Number 3
Number 4
Number 5
Number 6
Number 7
Number 10
Number 11
```

Comment: It's not sorting alphabetically.

Comment: This will only work if the string at the beginning is always 7 chars long... you can't guarantee that.

Answer (score 0):

sql has functions to cast a string to an integer while it's sorting.

If you are using mysql, this is what you'd use to do what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Number FROM database Order By CAST(Number AS UNSIGNED) ASC
```

If you are using a different database, you will need to google how to cast a column to an integer for your database.

Note: some of the other solutions work... but are kind of hacky - ie they look cool, but might not work in future. The above does exactly what you want and is how you are "supposed" to do it ;)

Comment: `SELECT CAST('Number 11' AS UNSIGNED)` yields `0`.

Comment: Why are you passing it a string with the word number in it? 
Don't pass "Number 11", pass "11" or the column named `Number`

Comment: Try: `SELECT CAST('11' AS UNSIGNED)` and you correctly get `11`

Comment: I'm passing that string because that's what's inside the `Number` column :)

Comment: Aha - yes, I see. I missed the part where it said it has a string and then a number...

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT DISTINCT Number FROM database WHERE 1 Order By substring_index(Number,'Number',1),cast(substring_index(Number,'Number ',-1) as unsigned int) ASC";
```

Comment: What would happen in case of 'The end'?

Comment: @Aquillo, do you mean `the end` instead of `Number` string?

Comment: Instead of 'Number 9' for example, as in the provided example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm much late but I faced the same issue. My answer could help those who are facing.
You can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function to solve this issue. Like your number is at the end of the string. Your query should be.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Number 
FROM database 
WHERE 1 Order By 0+SUBSTRING_INDEX(Number,' ',-1) 
ASC;
```

what this will do is it will take the last chunk of the text separated by space. and the 0+ will force to convert it to integer.

Answer (score 0):

try adding "+0" to the sort field:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Number FROM database WHERE 1 Order By Number+0 ASC
```