# SQL order by string order

Tags: mysql, sql

In my table i have two file one is **id** another is **strNum**. I want to order the **strNum** like as

```
One
Two
Three
```

My table data

```
    id  strNum      
------  ------------
     1  Two         
     2  One         
     3  Five        
     4  Nine
```

I want to get output without any extra field add. How can i will order like as

```
One
Two
Three
Four
Five
```

Comment: I'm confused, You don't have `Four` in the table.. So how is it in the result? You just wish to print a list of numbers names without any relation to the table?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, he's wanting order string number names by their numeric value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL order string as number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808573/sql-order-string-as-number)

Comment: @ShawnConn I got that too.. I just don't understand his result. I thought the desired result according to the table is: `One,Two,Five,Nine.`

Comment: what type of SQL? SQL Server? Oracle?

Comment: Added `mysql` tag based on the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query :

```
SELECT strNum FROM your_table
ORDER BY FIELD(strNum,'One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight','Nine','Ten') ASC
```

Comment: I'm interested in which flavour of SQL has the `FIELD` function?

Comment: `Field` is a `mysql` function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Case`:

```
select strNum
from A
order by case when strNum='one' then 1
                    when strNum='two' then 2
                    when strNum='three' then 3
                    when strNum='four' then 4
                    when strNum='five' then 5
                    when strNum='six' then 6
                    when strNum='seven' then 7
                    when strNum='eight' then 8
                    when strNum='nine' then 9
                    when strNum='ten' then 10  end
```

You didn't mention which DB you are using. This is PostgreSQL version.
See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c995f/1)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6a54c/1

Create a table containing all the mappings from number string to integer value

**TABLE_MAPING**

```
Value   strNum
------  ------------
     1  One         
     2  Two         
     3  Three        
     4  Four 
.....................
```

Now create your query with appropriate join

```
SELECT m.strNum FROM my_table m 
  JOIN table_mapping as maping on m.strNum = maping.strNum
  ORDER BY maping.value
```

Comment: In that case he doesn't really need a new table. He can add a column to his existed table to do the mapping.

Comment: This is much easier solution with a pre-populated  table of mappings.

Comment: It's another approach to solve the OP question. I just said that you can get the same result by adding a column to his table rather then create a new table. Alter the existed table to be:   `(id , strNum  , value)`.  You don't need two tables as you suggested:  `(id , strNum)`   `(strNum  , value)`.