# Laravel Order By returns weird order

Tags: laravel, sql-order-by

Hello everyone i have some information and i want to order them by the bill number
here is the array of data

```
[
    {
        "id": 162,
        "bill_number": "9",
        "created_at": "2020-09-15T16:21:47.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-09-15T16:28:40.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 161,
        "bill_number": "8",
        "created_at": "2020-09-15T16:06:56.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-09-15T16:07:09.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 164,
        "bill_number": "10",
        "created_at": "2020-09-15T16:28:51.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-09-15T16:29:24.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 151,
        "bill_number": "1",
        "created_at": "2020-09-15T15:18:47.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-09-15T15:19:13.000000Z"
    }
]
```

basically its a punch of bills

i am retrieving them like this

```
    $paid_bills = Bill::where([
        ['grand_total' , '!=' , 'null'],
        ['status' , 'payed']
    ])->orderBy('bill_number' , 'desc')
    ->get();
```

the what i am getting is like this

9

8

10

1

the simple question is why it is ordering it like this and how to fix it.
Thanks for your time

Note: i removed non-relevant data to save time

Comment: That's string ordering... Store the value as an integer, then you'll get the correct ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [orderByRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-methods)

and you can convert string column to integer by multiple it by 1 ...

```
 $paid_bills = Bill::where([
        ['grand_total' , '!=' , 'null'],
        ['status' , 'payed']
    ])->orderByRaw('bill_number*1 desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: That feels a little hacky... Why not a proper cast? Like `orderByRaw('CAST(bill_number as UNSIGNED) DESC')`?

Comment: great thank you very much worked perfectly i will up your question but i will give the answered mark to hxk1r because he gave us the lead

Comment: Please give checkmark to this answer, my answer is not correct at all by @TimLewis said.

Answer (score 0):

Your `bill_number` is currently string. To order them in DESC, you should use them as integer.

Use `"bill_number": 9,` instead of `"bill_number": "9",` on your bills, and apply this to all of them.

Remove the quotation mark.

Comment: i am getting the data from my database and the bill_number has String type because i need to use big numbers so how can i convert them  in the where statement ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808573/sql-order-string-as-number check this

Comment: I'm not a pro about Laravel, but I'm kinda sure that ordering by DESC works only in integers. And your `bill_number` is string. I'm confident about that

Comment: @hxk1r That's partially incorrect; `ORDER BY column DESC` works with all kinds of columns types; strings, integers, dates, time, etc. You're correct that `bill_number` is a string, but this is not static data; you can't just say "remove the quotations", as it doesn't work that way.

Comment: yes that is true the data is stored as string which explains the weird behavior of order by but as @TimLewis mentioned i can't just convert types by removing the quotations

Comment: @RYOK Follow-up, if you're going to be converting these strings to integers for ordering, is there a reason you can't just store them as integers? How big are these order numbers?

Comment: it can be 1 million 1 trillion i don't exactly know because it represents the number of bills created by a certain company

Comment: 1 million is not a big number (in terms of database numbering), and you're unlikely to ever have a trillion records in your database. I understand the hesitation, but I'd suggest converting :)

Comment: hmm i think you got a point i will put it as bigInt or something similar Thanks A lot @TimLewis