# filter mysql columns with different symbols

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to filter the data (from largest to smallest) and ran into a problem.
The column lines contain data in the form:

```
testColumn
0:1
1:2
2:3
3:4
```

etc.
And for example I have data like:

```
column123
99:123
9:123
8:34
81:1
1:2
11:17
5:4
55:72
9:12
```

I filter from largest to smallest and get:

```
column123
99:123
9:123
9:12
81:1
8:34
55:72
5:4
11:17
1:2
```

But I need something completely different. Specifically:

```
column123
99:123
81:1
55:72
11:17
9:123
9:12
8:34
5:4
1:2
```

I use the command

```
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY column123 DESC
```

for this and get what is above.

How can I filter the column the way I need?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL order string as number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808573/sql-order-string-as-number). If you want to order by both parts of the string (before and after `:`) then you will need to split it first. In this case, they should probably be stored in their own columns, instead of serialised.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SUBSTRING_INDEX and CAST functions to extract and convert the "X" and "Y" values before sorting.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column123, ':', 1) AS SIGNED) DESC, CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column123, ':', -1) AS SIGNED) DESC;
```