# Datatable.Select sort expression with some sql function

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable

I want to use some function in Sort Expression of Datatable.Select.
I try by this-

```
string strSelect="";
///Some code
string strSort="RIGHT(TESTID,2) DESC,SUBSTRING (TESTID,3,5) DESC, TESTDATE DESC";
dtOld.Select(strSelect,strSort );
```

but,I think there is something wrong by using sql function(eg.SUBSTRING) in Sort Expression.
SO, How can I sort my datatable by this sort expression? Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: If there is impossible to use SUBSTRING in Datatable.Select,is there any other ways to do this problem??

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any error message?

Not sure that will do but you have a space after SUBSTRING, SHOULD BE SUBSTRING(...,,).

I tested below for mysql and SQL server 2012 and it works:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('AAA BBBCCC',3,5);

Result: A BBB
```

Comment: I want to use this SUBSTRING() in Sort Condition but it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
string strSelect="RIGHT(TESTID,2) AS T1, SUBSTRING(TESTID,3,5) AS T2";
///Some code
string strSort="T1 DESC, T2 DESC, TESTDATE DESC";
dtOld.Select(strSelect, strSort);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939518/sorting-string-column-containing-numbers-in-sql