# Mysql order by, sorting doesn't work properly

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have table with names as `sth-1`, `sth-2`, .........`sth-10`, `sth-11` and so on.

I want to sort them serially but it fetches as `1, 11, 12, .., 2,3` and so on when sorted by name in `asc` order.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Note that you also have `natsort()` if you want to do it in PHP

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you if the numbers are always going to follow the -

```
SELECT   *
FROM     table
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(column,LOCATE('-',column)+1) AS SIGNED)
```

This original query is from

[Sorting string column containing numbers in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939518/sorting-string-column-containing-numbers-in-sql)

Adopted to your needs

Comment: Just want to note that this is only useful for small number of rows, because that way mysql could not use an index for sorting.

Comment: Yes that is true... a better option is to store this number separately in a field and update it with a trigger

Comment: Yes if that assumption is true then this can be done, the basic idea is that the sort should be on a number

Comment: I had seen the same answer, but it fetches the even rows only, 2, 4, 6 and so on. The odd rows are missing.

Comment: can you make a sqlfiddle, there is nothing here that filters the results so there could be some other part of the query that filters

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're trying to sort strings, not numbers.

One way out of this is to make a separate int column so it will be a bit faster on the sorting.

The other way is this one:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(column,LOCATE('-',column)+1) AS SIGNED)
```

Personally I prefer to use a separate column, so you don't really rely on the names format.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way of doing this is to sort by the length and then the field:

```
order by char_length(col), col
```